# PHP Facebook API Import photos not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to import my friend list and my personal data, but the import photos is not working.
'/me' works, '/me/friends' works but 'me/photos' and '/me/albums' do not work.
 I have googled and tried a few answers on stackoverflow but none seem to work. Well here is my code and I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
public function getuserpics(){
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $this->appid,
    'secret' => $this->appsecret,
));
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$params = array(
    'method' => 'get',
    'access_token' => $access_token
        );
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user){
    $logouturl = "logout.php";
    $str = "<a href=\"".$logouturl."\">Logout</a>";
    $ret[0] = 1;
    $ret[1] = $str;
    $albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums', $params);
    var_dump($albums);
    }
else {
        $loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    $str = "<a href=\"".$loginurl."\">Login With Facebook</a>";
    $ret[0] = 0;
    $ret[1] = $str;
    }
return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't ask for permissions.

```
$loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
```

becomes

```
$loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_photos'));
```

Read more about `getLoginUrl` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/).
And you will find the list of permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/).

Comment: Your code works for me. You need to reconnect to get the new permission. Make sure you aren't still logged in. So, try to clean your browser cache, remove the app from your Facebook settings and try again. If it still doesn't work, check your `php_error.log` for more information.

Comment: Perfect !!! .... It was an issue with the browser cache and facebook cookies ... worked as soon as I cleaned the cache :) Thank you very much for spending your valuable time to solve this !